# Spring MVC - Make JSP available

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring MVC application and the html pages are correctly display, altought, when i try to use JSP pages, it does not work (error displaying page like view file does not exist). I saw some example mixing xml configurations and beans for JSP pages, but none worked to me. Could yoou help me guiding me What configuration (xml config) is needed to use the JSP pages? Not sure if my problem was in the package structure.

PS: I do not have any XML file (web.xml or other) apart from the pom (maven being used) and the properties file with DB configuration.